# Python Decimal is not working as expected

Tags: python

Decimal(0.001) * -1 is not the same as Decimal(-0.001).

Similarly, Decimal(0.001) * Decimal(-1) is not the same as Decimal(-0.001).

Am I mad? How is it failing at such a simple task?

Comment: `Decimal(0.001)` is not the same as `Decimal('0.001')`.

Comment: Note that ``Decimal('0.001') * -1`` is the same as ``Decimal('-0.001')``. Your issue is the floating point math *before* conversion to ``Decimal``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: As per @MisterMiyagi's comment, if you print each of the values you'll see the problem. Printing things is a great first debugging step.

Comment: So is `Decimal(0.001) * Decimal(-1)` the correct way to use the package? I.e. never use floats as a calculation, ever?

Comment: @namesake ``Decimal('0.001')`` is the correct way. Note the quotes.

Comment: @namesake Just the opposite.  Use quoted strings.  Otherwise there's no point and you might as well use ordinary floats.  The whole point of using the decimal package is to *avoid* floating point arithmetic.  So use `Decimal('0.001')`  to properly construct the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

This is another variant of ["Is floating point math broken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

When you do `Decimal(0.001)`, you're turning a non-exact floating point value into a Decimal (that valiantly makes it exact):

```
>>> Decimal(0.001)
Decimal('0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')
```

When you use a string representation, you get the exact Decimal too.

```
>>> Decimal("0.001")
Decimal('0.001')
```

When you do math on a Decimal, [the decimal context's `precision` value](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/decimal.html#context-objects) abides, which is why you see a truncation/rounding:

```
>>> Decimal(-0.001)
Decimal('-0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')
>>> Decimal(-0.001) * -1
Decimal('0.001000000000000000020816681712')
```